# Spring batch- parallel processing of two tasks but second task has dependency on first task

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-batch

I am using `spring batch` for `processing` `large data`.

My problem is I have two different `Tasklet` that are `executing` `one after another`. I can not run it parallel as second tasklet has some dependency one first `Tasklet`. In order to save the time I would like to start next `Tasklet` immediately after the first few `items` has been `processed` by previous `tasklet`.  As `Spring Batch` uses a `Chunk Oriented` processing style. Can `ItemWriter` of one `Tasklet`, pass chunk of already processed items to another `Tasklet`'s `ItemReader` or `ItemProcessor` or `ItemWriter` for next processing?  But while the another `tasklet` is working on the `chunk`, previous `tasklet` should `NOT` wait and it should continue `iteration` over `next` `chunk`.

Comment: Is the dependency per-item? Could you just use a single reader and a composite item processor/writer?

Comment: @DeanClark I need next Task to be started after `ItemWriter` written out the chuck of items in the databse. My next Task's `ItemReader` will pick these item from the database or in other case I can also pass the list of items to the next Task's `ItemWriter` but these item should be committed in the database before they process in next step. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description and additional information above, I would simply leverage a `CompositeItemWriter` to accomplish this.

The list of items will first be written by WriterOne and then be passed to and written by WriterTwo.

```
<bean id="compositeWriter" 
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
    <property name="delegates">
        <list>
            <ref bean="writerOne" />
            <ref bean="writerTwo" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="writerOne"  ...  />
<bean id="writerTwo"  ...  />
```

Comment: Is that possible - when the `writerTwo` is processing on the chunk of items, `Tasklet` should NOT wait and `ItemReader` should continue `iteration` over `next chunk`? If you have noticed, in my question I also asked that `while the another tasklet is working on the chunk, previous tasklet should NOT wait and it should continue iteration over next chunk`. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the concern that the second operation (the one performed by `writerTwo`) will take much longer than the first operation? Typically the overhead of re-reading and parsing records and the associated IO that comes with it would make reading the same data twice less appealing than having two synchronous writers.